# scipy.spatial ValueError: "x must consist of vectors of length %d but has shape %s"

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

[Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) has an excelent [spatial analysis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) pack which includes a K-dimensional tree.
I am attempting to use the query function and it is returning this error:

> ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 6 but has shape (2,)

Does anyone know what this error is referring to?

From some google searching I have discovered it has this general format:

```
raise ValueError("x must consist of vectors of length %d but has shape %s" % (self.m, np.shape(x)))
```

I believe [This](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py) is the source code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Without knowing how you have instantiated your K-tree, and what are you querying it with, it is hard to figure out what may be going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

This particular value error is referencing the length of the array used to build the KD Tree.

The `%d` value represents the length of the array used to build the KD tree, and the `%s` value represents the length of the array like object you are using to query.

In my example the `%d` value was 6 because I had built a 6 dimensional array.
The `%s` value was 2 because I had only fed it two coordinates: `(X,Y)` to query.

My error was that I had accidentally included 4 extra fields when building the KD tree. Now that both values are 2, all works as expected.