# scipy.spatial ValueError when trying to run kdtree

Tags: python, numpy, kdtree

**Background:** I am trying to run a nearest neighbor using the `cKDtree` function on a shapefile that has 201 records with lat/lons against a time series dataset of 8760 hours (total hours in a year). I am getting an error, naturally I looked it up. I found this: [scipy.spatial ValueError: "x must consist of vectors of length %d but has shape %s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264682/scipy-spatial-valueerror-x-must-consist-of-vectors-of-length-d-but-has-shape) which is the same error, but I am having trouble understanding how exactly this error was resolved.

**Workflow:** I pulled the x & y coordinates out of the shapefile and stored them in separate arrays called `x_vector` and `y_vector`. The 8760 data is an hdf5 file. I pulled the coordinates out using `h5_coords = np.vstack([meta['latitude'], meta['longitude']]).T`.

Now I try to run the kdtree,

```
# Run the kdtree to match nearest values
tree = cKDTree(np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector]))
kdtree_indices = tree.query(h5_coords)[1]
```

but it results in this same traceback error.

**Traceback Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "meera_extract.py", line 45, in <module>
kdtree_indices = tree.query(h5_coords)[1]
File "scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx", line 618, in scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.query (scipy/spatial/ckdtree.cxx:6996)
ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 201 but has shape (1, 389880)
```

Help me, stackoverflow. You're my only hope.

Comment: What is the output of `x_vector.shape`, `y_vector.shape` and `h5_coords.shape`?

Comment: Instead of passing `np.vstack([...])` to `cKDTree`, take a smaller step and use `points = np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector])`.  Then take a look at `points.shape`.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: `x_vector.shape` & `y_vector.shape` are (201,) and `h5_coords.shape` is `(1, 389880)`.

Comment: Ah, in that case, `np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector])` has shape `(2, 201)`.  That means you are passing `cKDTree` just two points in 201-dimensional space.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I did as you suggested, `vector_pnts = np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector])`. The shape is now (2, 201). Not sure what I am looking for...

Comment: `vector_pnts = np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector]).T`, isn't this what you want?

Comment: Use `np.column_stack()` instead of `numpy.vstack()`.

Comment: Ok that flipped it so now `vector_pnts.shape` is (201, 2), but still having the same overall error.

Comment: Is the error now `ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 2 but has shape (1, 389880)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser oops yes it changed from `length 201` to `length 2`

Comment: `h5_coords` is *not* a collection of point in 2-d space.  You have to fix how it is created.   You say you used `h5_coords = np.vstack([meta['latitude'], meta['longitude']]).T`.  That is not creating an array of the correct shape.  Try using `column_stack`, and don't transpose.  (To be sure, we need to know the shape of `meta['latitude']`.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! `meta['latitude'].shape` is `(194940, 1)`. Doing as you suggested & using `column_stack` without the transpose worked. `h5_coords.shape` is now `(194940, 2)` and the kdtree matched. It seems that I was stuck on `vstack`, but `column_stack` was what was needed. I need to read up on the difference of those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems I need to read up on the differences of `vstack` & `column_stack` and the use of transpose i.e. `.T`. If anyone has the same issue here is what I changed to make the `cKDtree` work. Hopefully it will help if someone else runs into this issue. Many thanks to comments from the community to help solve this!

I changed how the `hdf5` coordinates were brought in from `vstack` to `column_stack` and removing the transpose `.T`.

```
# Get coordinates of HDF5 file
h5_coords = np.column_stack([meta['latitude'], meta['longitude']])
```

Instead of trying to add the points in the tree I made a new variable to hold them:

```
# combine x and y
vector_pnts = np.column_stack([x_vector, y_vector])
```

Then I ran the kdtree without any error.

```
# Run the kdtree to match nearest values
tree = cKDTree(vector_pnts)
kdtree_indices = tree.query(h5_coords)[1]
```